# C++ - Deprecated conversion from string constant to char

Tags: c++

I don't understand why my compiler is giving me a warning about a deprecated conversion from string to char.

this is where is complaining about the warning:

Just a bit of background of what I'm doing.. I'm trying to understand and practice Exceptions... I'm not sure if its better to just work with char[1000] for the First name and so on.. I will really appreciate if someone help to understand the warning and help me to find a solution.. Thanks..

=================================================================================

```
class TeLoEnYuco
{
string FN, LN, R;
    double Income;

public:
    const char *getters(){return FN.data(), LN.data(), R.data();}
    virtual char *getFacilityAccess()=0;
    TeLoEnYuco(char *fn, char *ln, char r, double inc)
    {
        if(fn==0) throw Exception(1, "First Name is Null"); //Warning #1
        if(ln==0) throw Exception(2, "Last Name is Null");  //Warning #2
        if(r==0) throw Exception(3, "Rank is Null");        //Warning #3
        if(inc<=0) throw Exception(4, "Income is Null");    //Warning #4

        FN=fn;
        LN=ln;
        R=r;
        Income=inc;
    }
};
```

=====================Exception class=================================

```
class Exception
{
    int Code;
    string Mess;

public:
    Exception(int cd, char *mess)
    {
        Code=cd;
        Mess=mess;
    }
    int getCode(){return Code;}
    const char *getMess(){return Mess.data();}
};
```

Comment: Which line is the error on? What is the actual error message?

Comment: How is `Exception` defined?

Comment: `getters` is returning 3 values?

Comment: The warning is the same as the title of my post, deprecated conversion from string to char

Comment: @DrewMcGowen, that's not what the comma operator means

Comment: Just an FYI, but there's a stack exchange for reviewing code.  Here's the link: [codereview.se]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I assume `Exception`'s constructor signature is

```
Exception(int, char*)
```

You pass a string literal as a parameter, whose actual type is `const char*`, but the implicit conversion to `char*` is legal pre-C++11 (but deprecated, so you get the warning).

Modify the signature to

```
Exception(int, const char*)
```

or, better yet,

```
Exception(int, const std::string&)
```

To summarize:

```
char* x       = "stringLiteral";  //legal pre-C++11, deprecated
const char* y = "stringLiteral";  // good
std::string z  ("stringLiteral"); // even better
```

Comment: The type of a string literal is `const char[N]`